# Can CArchive read and write from a specified location of a file?

Tags: mfc, carchive

I want to serialize and deserialize a list of objects into a file. But I found that if I use CArchive, the new content will overwrite the original content in the file, which is not my expectation. Is there any method to allow me to read and write from a specified location in the file?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CArchive has a c'tor that takes a ptr to a CFile. Maybe if you pass it a file with the current pointer correctly set, it will do the trick.